# How to accept numbers with decimal points with any length?

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to ask if what HTML code should I use to accept numbers with decimal places without any length and that will not have any problem with my database. Apparently I encountered being unable to store data in my database table beacause my inputted data lacked the length needed. Example, I put step as equal to 0.0001, however if I input something like 25.12, it won't save any data. Hence if I don't put step, it still won't save any data. Help please?

Comment: post you db table schema

Comment: Your question is very vague, but it _might_ be that you are looking for a solution implementing "arbitrary precision for fractions". There are multiple solutions (libraries and such) for that, but keep in mind that this is very inefficient, since you have to store such numbers and strings and convert them all the time.

Comment: Float with no scale/precision

Answer (score 0):

> on your database, change data type of your input to decimal,
>
> ex. fieldname ( datatype//decimal, decimal places//4)